# Installing drivers in Windows 8 silently without OS prompts(pop ups)

Tags: windows-8, driver, silent-installer

We have a device with Windows 8 embedded OS. We need to install cypress USB drivers while updating our application and do it silently without any OS pop ups, as users won't have input device to accept the prompt dialog.

I have used PNPUtil.exe and DpInst.exe with /S /Q option combinations. Either installation does not happen or it happens with OS prompt. 
I tried signing our drivers with code sign certificate still there OS prompt pops up.

I have also tried disabling EnableLUA option in the registry, but still issue exists.

I have used following to tools with all relevant flags, still we could not suppress the OS prompt.

```
pnputil.exe /S -i -a Drivers/win8/x86/
dpinst-x86.exe /S /PATH Drivers/win8/x86/
```

I would like to know :

1. Whether this is possible?
2. Does any installer framework support such installation?
3. Can creating a sub process and making it install the drivers in a programmatic way serve the purpose?
4. Can we modify the registry to suppress these prompts?

Comment: I like to see an answer to this question ,too!

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: if I could I would have left this as a comment.

For this scenario I've always used DISM. You can mount your image and install software, drivers or anything you like and then silently blast the image onto a machine. If reinstalling isn't an option please disregard.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism---deployment-image-servicing-and-management-technical-reference-for-windows